# Merge dataframe resulting in Series

Tags: python, pandas

I working with the Texas Hospital Discharge Dataset and I am trying to determine the top 100 most frequent Principal Surgery Procedures over a period of 4 years.

Do to this I need to go through each quarter of each year and count the procedures, but when I try to merge different quarters the result is a Series not a DataFrame.

```
top_procedures = None

for year in range(6, 10):
    for quarter in range(1, 5):
        quarter_data = pd.read_table(
            filepath_or_buffer="/path/to/texas/data/PUDF_base"
                               + str(quarter) + "q200" + str(year) + "_tab.txt",
        )

        quarter_data = quarter_data[quarter_data["THCIC_ID"] != 999999]
        quarter_data = quarter_data[quarter_data["THCIC_ID"] != 999998]

        quarter_procedures = quarter_data["PRINC_SURG_PROC_CODE"].value_counts()
        quarter_procedures = pd.DataFrame(
            {"PRINC_SURG_PROC_CODE": quarter_procedures.index, "count": quarter_procedures.values})

        top_procedures = quarter_procedures if (top_procedures is None) else \
            top_procedures.merge(
                right=quarter_procedures,
                how="outer",
                on="PRINC_SURG_PROC_CODE"
            ).set_index(
                ["PRINC_SURG_PROC_CODE"]
            ).sum(
                axis=1
            )
```

Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong? From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) it looks like it should return a DataFrame.

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the merge will indeed return a dataframe, but in your code you are summing on axis=1 (all values in one row) after merging which then gives you a series (since the values from all columns are summed together in one final column).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there any way to transform it into a DataFrame? Besides what I already use in the code.

Comment: Try  `...).sum(axis=1).to_frame()` Have a look at the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html?highlight=series%20to_frame#pandas.Series.to_frame)